# Daemon not started by systemd

Tags: systemd

I am facing a weird problem, my daemon is not started automatically by systemd. 
Please find my `.service` file below.

```
[Unit]
Description=System Log daemon
Requires=basic.target
After=basic.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/utild
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my systemctl status output

```
● utility.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 1970-01-01 00:00:33 UTC; 48 years 2 months ago
 Main PID: 1641 (utild)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemlog.service
           └─1641 /usr/bin/utild
```

Could anyone tell me whats was the problem with this.

I reloded my system and got a new output for `systemctl status`

```
● systemlog.service - System Log daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/utility.service)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 1970-01-01 00:00:31 UTC; 48 years 2 months ago
 Main PID: 1639 (sharedBuf)
   CGroup: /system.slice/utility.service
           └─1639 /usr/bin/sharedBuf
```

Still my daemon is not running.  No luck with `systemctl daemon-reload`, but once I do `systemctl restart`, my daemon is started.

Comment: On the contrary , you have an outstanding runtime on that daemon!

Comment: Sry jeff, i am new to writing systemd service file and I dont get you

Comment: Did you maybe rename/move/delete the `utility.service` file after starting the service?

Comment: No, utility.service is there at /systemd/system

Comment: What happens if you do `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: I reloded my system and got a new output for systemctl status

● systemlog.service - System Log daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/utility.service)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 1970-01-01 00:00:31 UTC; 48 years 2 months ago
 Main PID: 1639 (sharedBuf)
   CGroup: /system.slice/utility.service
           └─1639 /usr/bin/sharedBuf
still my daemon is not running....

no luck with systemctl daemon-reload, but once I do systemctl restart, my daemon is started

Comment: You're saying your daemon isn't running, but systemd is claiming that `/usr/bin/utild` (PID 1641) is running (and in your update, PID 1639 (`/usr/bin/sharedBuf`)). Is this process not running? (Does it show up in e.g. `ps aux`?)